# With nats can I export a stream from one account to different accounts which can import on the same topic?

Tags: publish-subscribe, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I'm using nats and I'm not sure if it will be able to do what I'm attempting.  My understanding is that accounts will allow me to have overlapping subjects since [the subject space is not globally shared](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/accounts).

What I'd like to be able to do is have different users (in different accounts) subscribe to the same subject in their account with another application user/account publishing separately to each of them?

So, if I have the following three users/accounts:

```
accounts: {
    A: {
        users: [
            {user: a, password: a}
        ]
    },
    B: {
        users: [
            {user: b, password: b}
        ]
    },
    C: {
        users: [
            {user: c, password: c}
        ]
    },
}
```

I'd like users b and c to subscribe to `mysubject` (which are non-overlapping in their own account) and have user a publish to each of them separately.

Having read and re-read the documentation a few times, it doesn't seem like that's possible because I'd need to export different streams from user a that users b and c could import separately?

I'm really just looking to confirm that this is the case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find at [Multi Tenancy using Accounts](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/accounts#import-export-example)

```
accounts: {
    A: {
        users: [
            {user: a, password: a}
        ]
        exports: [
            {stream: puba.>}
            {service: pubq.>}
            {stream: b.>, accounts: [B]}
            {service: q.b, accounts: [B]}
        ]
    },
    B: {
        users: [
            {user: b, password: b}
        ]
        imports: [
            {stream: {account: A, subject: b.>}}
            {service: {account: A, subject: q.b}}
        ]
    }
    C: {
        users: [
            {user: c, password: c}
        ]
        imports: [
            {stream: {account: A, subject: puba.>}, prefix: from_a}
            {service: {account: A, subject: pubq.C}, to: Q}
        ]
    }
}
```